# JFreeChart / JasperReports - Setting tick labels to only show on one axis for bar chart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a horizontal bar chart. I want to make it such that I only show the labels for the domains, but not the range because I already have labels at the end of each bar showing their exact value. This is what the bar chart currently looks like :

[image]

I want to get rid of the tick labels on the range (0, 25, 50, 75, 100) while keeping the tick labels on the domain. How can I do this without getting rid of both? I've tried :

```
public class BarCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
         BarRenderer  renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer(); 
         renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.99);
         renderer.setItemMargin(-2);

         ValueAxis rangeAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getRangeAxis();
         rangeAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(false);

         rangeAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    }   
}
```

But this just makes labels on both axis go invisible.

Comment: Starting from [`BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java), `rangeAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false)` produces the expected result: only the range axis labels are affected.

Comment: @trashgod It didn't produce the expected result for me. I instead solved the problem by setting the flags for BOTH axis, setting the tick labels visible for domain axis to true while setting the range axis to false. Weird bug, I checked the jrxml and by default the chart should set the tick labels visible (it indeed set those labels visible when I commented out the setTickLabelsVisible line). But I was able to solve the problem.

Comment: Interesting. I'm unfamiliar with JasperReports; but if it might help fellow travelers, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting the setTickLabelsVisible for both axis (even though by default the domain axis should show the tick labels). It seems that setting only one of the axis would result in setting true or false for both axis (weird bug). So setting the domain axis to setTickLabelsVisible(true) while setting the range axis setTickLabelsVisible(false) solved my issue.